# jQuery file upload: example working but not when I try to include it in my site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have been trying to implement [File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in the site I'm working on but haven't been successful.
If I just copy the files to a test directory on `https://static.mysite.com/z_test/index.html`
then the example works fine.
If I try to include all the CSS/JS files in a .php file (that uses Xtemplates) and then copy&paste the relevant code from their example it won't work, no selected files will be displayed.
My Site's URL looks like `https://mysite.com/test-upload` and loads CSS/JS files from `https://static.mysite.com/css/... and https://static.mysite.com/js/`
could that be the reason why it won't work?
Any suggestions on what (else) I should try to make it work would are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site, or post some code that doesn't work?  Also, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I cannot post the link here but "doesn't work" means: I click on "Add Files", select an image and then "Open" and the image won't be listed on the web page.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's not possible to help.

Comment: I could surely provide you with access in a private chat but I'm not sure how I could open such a chat.

Comment: If you can't post YOUR code, then post example code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a file permissions issue. Check if the path where the files are uploaded on the server has the right permissions.

Comment: Well, the problem at this point isn't related to permissions because I do not attempt to upload anything to the server yet, I just select an image and that image won't appear inside my page.

Comment: No, not a single one. I also included all the CSS/JS files in the example code from https://static.mysite.com/css/... and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it was related to some overlapping CSS classes, that's why I couldn't see any JS errors.